# Format a number to string in Flutter

Tags: flutter, intl

I have build a sign up system with phone number Input in Flutter with the `intl_phone_field` package. Now I have to format this number to a string to fill it in a database. Is there any way to do this. I could not found anything for this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I thought it already returned as `Sting`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the `completeNumber` getter as described in the doc?

```
IntlPhoneField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Phone Number',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(),
        ),
    ),
    initialCountryCode: 'IN',
    onChanged: (phone) {
        print(phone.completeNumber);
    },
)
```